# Select from one table with two foreign keys in a single query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I have tow tables:

```
User:
user_id

user_blogs:
user_id | blog_id

blogs:
blog_id | source | identifier

Comments:
source | identifier | Field3
```

I want to be able to select all comments in the blogs that a user owns.

My models are related:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_blogs
  has_many :blogs, trhough: :user_blogs
end

class blogs < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, 
           :foreign_key => :source,
           :primary_key => :source,
           :conditions => Proc.new {
              {:identifier=> self.identifier}
           }
end
```

Right now I can retrieve all user comments using this:

```
User.first.blogs.map{|b| b.comments}
```

But this creates one query for each blog.

Is there a way to do this in one single step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_blogs
  has_many :blogs, through: :user_blogs
  has_many :comments, through: :blogs
end

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, -> { where(identifier: identifier) }, foreign_key : source, primary_key: source
end


User.find(ID).comments
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use Rails *eager_loading* feature.

```
u = User.includes(blogs: :comments)
# now you can do
u.first.blogs.map { |b| b.comments }
```

Or, you can modify your model *association* definition also :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_blogs
  has_many :blogs, -> { includes(:comments) }, through: :user_blogs
end
```

Now, you can do the below without hitting multiple queries for each `blog`.

```
User.first.blogs.map { |b| b.comments }
```